# How do I make floated DIV's take up the horizontal space of their container?

Tags: html, css

This is what I'm talking about:

```css
#row {
    border: solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cell {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid pink;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="row">
    <div class="cell">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas efficitur tincidunt sapien, sed hendrerit metus pharetra et. Mauris nec turpis faucibus, mattis purus sed, tempus risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus rutrum luctus dapibus. Integer sed sodales sem, quis accumsan augue. Mauris non augue dignissim, vestibulum risus nec, convallis augue. Integer quis elit et nisl facilisis pellentesque sit amet at dui. Maecenas vitae nisl congue, ornare turpis in, malesuada sem. In eu eleifend nulla. Donec est tellus, tincidunt volutpat eleifend vel, pellentesque et leo. Maecenas purus justo, scelerisque blandit ultrices non, facilisis id diam. Sed gravida tincidunt nunc ut sollicitudin.
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas efficitur tincidunt sapien, sed hendrerit metus pharetra et. Mauris nec turpis faucibus, mattis purus sed, tempus risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas efficitur tincidunt sapien, sed hendrerit metus pharetra et. Mauris nec turpis faucibus, mattis purus sed, tempus risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus rutrum luctus dapibus. Integer sed sodales sem, quis accumsan augue. Mauris non augue dignissim, vestibulum risus nec, convallis augue. Integer quis elit et nisl facilisis pellentesque sit amet at dui.        
    </div>
</div>
```

I wan the pink cells to fill up the <strike>horizontal</strike> *vertical* space of the row DIV. If i don't float them left they do this, but I need them to be uniformly sized across the row. This is a simplification of my actual code, but this is the problem I am facing.

Comment: Are you trying to get your divs to stretch vertically to the bottom of the parent div, or "fill up the horizontal space of the row DIV" as you mention in your question? Your divs are already stretched horizontally, so I assumed that you meant vertically stretch in terms of height.

Comment: Where is the problem? You have already got what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `display: table-cell` and remove `float: left` from elements with class `.cell`:

```css
#row {
    border: solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid pink;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="row">
    <div class="cell">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas efficitur tincidunt sapien, sed hendrerit metus pharetra et. Mauris nec turpis faucibus, mattis purus sed, tempus risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus rutrum luctus dapibus. Integer sed sodales sem, quis accumsan augue. Mauris non augue dignissim, vestibulum risus nec, convallis augue. Integer quis elit et nisl facilisis pellentesque sit amet at dui. Maecenas vitae nisl congue, ornare turpis in, malesuada sem. In eu eleifend nulla. Donec est tellus, tincidunt volutpat eleifend vel, pellentesque et leo. Maecenas purus justo, scelerisque blandit ultrices non, facilisis id diam. Sed gravida tincidunt nunc ut sollicitudin.
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas efficitur tincidunt sapien, sed hendrerit metus pharetra et. Mauris nec turpis faucibus, mattis purus sed, tempus risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas efficitur tincidunt sapien, sed hendrerit metus pharetra et. Mauris nec turpis faucibus, mattis purus sed, tempus risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus rutrum luctus dapibus. Integer sed sodales sem, quis accumsan augue. Mauris non augue dignissim, vestibulum risus nec, convallis augue. Integer quis elit et nisl facilisis pellentesque sit amet at dui.        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks identical to the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of floating, use `display:table-cell` instead:

```css
#row {
  border: solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid pink;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="row">
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas efficitur tincidunt sapien, sed hendrerit metus pharetra et. Mauris nec turpis faucibus, mattis purus sed, tempus risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
    nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus rutrum luctus dapibus. Integer sed sodales sem, quis accumsan augue. Mauris non augue dignissim, vestibulum risus nec, convallis augue. Integer quis elit et nisl facilisis pellentesque sit amet at dui. Maecenas vitae
    nisl congue, ornare turpis in, malesuada sem. In eu eleifend nulla. Donec est tellus, tincidunt volutpat eleifend vel, pellentesque et leo. Maecenas purus justo, scelerisque blandit ultrices non, facilisis id diam. Sed gravida tincidunt nunc ut sollicitudin.</div>
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas efficitur tincidunt sapien, sed hendrerit metus pharetra et. Mauris nec turpis faucibus, mattis purus sed, tempus risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
    nascetur ridiculus mus.</div>
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas efficitur tincidunt sapien, sed hendrerit metus pharetra et. Mauris nec turpis faucibus, mattis purus sed, tempus risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
    nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus rutrum luctus dapibus. Integer sed sodales sem, quis accumsan augue. Mauris non augue dignissim, vestibulum risus nec, convallis augue. Integer quis elit et nisl facilisis pellentesque sit amet at dui.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks identical to the OP.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - it does? I have `display: table-cell;` in `.cell` and he has `float: left;`.

Comment: Nope, something on your end. Just checked in Chrome, FF, and IE.

Comment: The float was removed and the display:table-cell added, so that the boxes extend to the full height of the parent.

Comment: Didn't the OP ask about *width?*

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what the OP wants then. In his example the divs already take up the full horizontal space of the parent.

Comment: I'd say he misspoke, but he also said *across, not down.*  Oh, well.  I figured he meant the lines in the middle were double-width.

Comment: I meant vertically. Sorry. I edited my post. I chose the other answer because it was the first in the list. I upped both answers though. They were the same thing. Thanks.